# NiFi web ui not open after enabled auth

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, apache-nifi

Configured NiFi 1.1.1 version in windows.

I have enabled client certificate auth with the following properties

**nifi.properties**

```
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.https.host=hostname
nifi.web.https.port=8080
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200

nifi.security.keystore=./conf/ssl/server.keystore
nifi.security.keystoreType=JKS
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=server_password
nifi.security.keyPasswd=server_keypassword
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/ssl/server.truststore
nifi.security.truststoreType=JKS
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=server_password
nifi.security.needClientAuth=true
nifi.security.user.authorizer=file-provider
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=
```

**authorizers.xml**

```
    <authorizer>
        <identifier>file-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity"></property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File">./conf/authorized-users.xml</property>

        <!-- Provide the identity (typically a DN) of each node when clustered, see above description of Node Identity.
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 2"></property>
        -->
    </authorizer>
```

**authorized-users.xml**

```
<users>
    <user dn="CN=Kumar">
        <role name="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <role name="ROLE_DFM"/>
    </user>
</users>
```

Followed [Generating server and client ssl certificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347116)

Everything was good. NiFi server started and got logs as UI is available in following URLs:

https://hostname:8080/nifi

But when i open UI in browser both in firefox and chrome, Nifi web url cannot open and it shows

`Secure Connection Failed` in firefox and `This site can’t be reached` in chrome

It didn't ask for client certificate.

What i did wrong? How can i achieve this?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok fine what is your doubt in this

Comment: How to open NiFi web ui? Why it didn't asked for client certificate?

Comment: Seriously I dont know

Comment: Did you create a client certificate and import it into your browser?

Comment: Is this an upgrade of a 0.x install? If not, you should populate an *Initial Admin Identity* in `authorizers.xml`, remove the *Legacy Authorized Users File* value, and delete `conf/users.xml` and `conf/authorizations.xml` and restart NiFi.

Comment: @Andy i have removed two files and populated Initial Admin Identity but still the same problem. I cannot open the NiFi web UI.

Comment: Try running the below command to verify that the server is running and properly negotiating TLS handshakes: 

`$ openssl s_client -connect <host:port> -debug -state -cert <path_to_your_cert.pem> -key <path_to_your_key.pem> -CAfile <path_to_your_CA_cert.pem>`

Where:

* <host:port> is the NiFi host & port

Comment: * <path_to_your_cert.pem> is the public certificate of another connecting node/client/etc. In the case that you do not have any other certs, you can use the certificate identifying NiFi, as it will be trusted by the truststore (because it is signed by the same CA certificate/itself)
* <path_to_your_key.pem> is the private key, PEM-encoded, of the same certificate as above. Again, last resort, the private key of NiFi will work
* <path_to_your_CA_cert.pem> is the public certificate of the CA that signed the NiFi node certificate, or the node certificate itself if self-signed.

Comment: @Andy i have tried and got http://pastebin.com/sv6XMwA4

Comment: Verify return code 18 means you did not provide the CA cert in the command, but that shouldn't be stopping your browser from making the connection.

Comment: Have you tried using private browsing mode in either browser or importing the client certificate directly into your OS keychain (for Chrome)?

Comment: Yes i have tried in private window and also imported certificate to Trusted Root in my machine. But still not working.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using Apache NiFi's tls-toolkit in order to facilitate certificate generation.  It can generate a Certificate Authority (to import into the browser), keystore and truststore for NiFi as well as a client p12 file in a single command.

You can get it from the NiFi download page as part of the nifi-toolkit.

Both NiFi (starting with version 1.0) and the nifi-toolkit require Java 8 to run.

If you run (replacing YOUR_HOSTNAME with your actual hostname):

```
bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n YOUR_HOSTNAME -C 'CN=Kumar'
```

You should wind up with a YOUR_HOSTNAME directory containing a keystore, truststore, nifi.properties as well as a p12 and password file for your client certificate.

You'll want to import nifi-cert.pem into your browser as a trusted CA so that it knows it can trust the server.

Then import the client p12 into the browser using the password provided in the .password file.

(edit for code formatting, adding to answer)

Comment: When i run this command, i am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/nifi/toolkit/tls/TlsTo
olkitMain : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"

Comment: After importing certificate into Browser, it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Kumar I'm glad that worked for you :).  I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I'll add the Java 8 requirement also.